# How to force a SQL Server 2008 database to go Offline

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

How do I force my Database to go Offline, without regard to what or who is already using it?

I tried:

```
ALTER DATABASE database-name SET OFFLINE;
```

But it's still hanging after 7 min.

I want this because I need to test the scenario.

If it's even possible?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Go offline

```
USE master
GO
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabaseName
SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
```

Go online

```
USE master
GO
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabaseName
SET ONLINE
GO
```

Comment: @radbyx: MSDN says to use `master` when operating DB's state

Comment: @radbyx: If you USE MY_DATABASE, then ALTER DATABASE MY_DATABASE SET OFFLINE will fail, *because* you're using it! Yes, I just got stung by that...

Comment: Didnt work for me:

Msg 5061, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database 'MyDatabase'. Try again later.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.

Comment: I've seen occurences where you still need to use an 'sp_who2 active'/'sp_whoisactive' to see some stubborn connections from scheduled job machines or middletier stuff and run KILL with the SPID number to get rid of them

Answer (score 28):

You need to use `WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` to boot other conections out with no regards to what or who is is already using it.

Or use `WITH NO_WAIT` to not hang and not kill existing connections. See http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLOffline.aspx for details